# How to attach JSON data to an element to retrieve later in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `TableComponent` which takes pulls data from API and tries to represent is inside a table. I'll write a minimal reproducible example.

My render method look like this:

```
const tableRows = this.renderTableRow();

return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Application Name</th>
          <th>Total Valid Licenses</th>
          <th>Current in Use</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {tableRows}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

`renderTableRow` is as follows, note that `this.state.message` has all the data retrieved from the API (n number of objects which are about to be rendered as a table row):

```
return this.state.message.map(arr =>  // arr also has a key used_by which has a list of strings
  <tr onClick={this.handleClick}>
    <td>{arr.app_name}</td>
    <td>{arr.valid_licenses}</td>
    <td>{arr.inuse_licenses}</td>
  </tr>
)
```

On `handleClick` I want to show a modal with `used_by` data for that row.

With Vanilla JavaScript I could have done it something like this:

```
let row = table.insertRow();
row.dataset.used_by = arr.used_by;
row.dataset.license_server = arr.license_server;
row.addEventListener("click", showModal);
```

And in `showModal()` I can get `used_by` by `this.dataset.used_by`.

Comment: You may refer one of my [latest posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60436498/11299053) that does (among other things) what you described above.

Comment: Your modal could be a separate component which receives corresponding row's data as a prop. Let your onClick handler pass the data like so: `onClick= () => handleClick(arr.used_by)` and let it render this new modal component with passed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Wrap in an anon function

```
<tr onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event, arr)}>
```

Then you can pass the current arr data to the handle click, Which i assume is responsible for setting the popup.

## State management solution

You could send a redux/context action onClick to set the value of `currentActiveRow`. This can then always be read by default by your modal if you useSelector or useContext hook.