# I want to add edit button on my table and open the form on model when click demo modal button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

everyone, I want to add edit functionality into my project but I didn't understand how I can add that so can you please help me and I want to open my form on a modal on a button click "When they click on the button the modal will be open with the form" "when clicking on the edit button again modal will open with predefined values and when I edit the fields the table will be update " 
here is my code

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Form from "./Form";
//import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

import "./styles.css";



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      people: []
    };

    this.addPerson = this.addPerson.bind(this);
    this.deletePerson = this.deletePerson.bind(this);
  }

  addPerson(name, email, phone) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      people: [...prevState.people, { name, email, phone }]
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPeople();
  }

  getPeople() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => this.setState({ people: response }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  deletePerson(email) {
    return () => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        people: prevState.people.filter(person => person.email !== email)
      }));
    };
  }

  editPerson(email) {
    return () => {
      this.setState({email})
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form addPerson={this.addPerson} />
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>LP</TableCell>
              <TableCell>USER</TableCell>
              <TableCell>EMAIL</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Phone</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Actions</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {this.state.people.map((person, index) => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={person.email}>
                  <TableCell>{index + 1}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{person.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{person.email}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{person.phone}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                  <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={this.editPerson(person.email)}>
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={this.deletePerson(person.email)}>
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Form.js**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Modal from './Modal'

const validEmailRegex = RegExp(
  /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i
);
class Form extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.formSubmit = this.formSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name: null,
      email: null,
      phone: null,
      errors: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
      }
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    let errors = this.state.errors;

    switch (name) {
      case 'name':
        errors.name =
          value.length < 5
            ? 'Name must be 5 characters long!'
            : '';
        break;
      case 'email':
        errors.email =
          validEmailRegex.test(value)
            ? ''
            : 'Email is not valid!';
        break;
      case 'phone':
        errors.phone =
          value.length < 8
            ? 'Password must be 8 characters long!'
            : '';
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    this.setState({ errors, [name]: value }, () => {
      console.log(errors)
    })
  }

  formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.target;
    const email = form.elements["email"].value;
    const name = form.elements["name"].value;
    const phone = form.elements["phone"].value;
    this.props.addPerson(name, email, phone);
    form.reset();
  }

  state = { show: false };

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };

  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Modal />
        <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>

          <TextField onChange={this.handleChange} id="name" type="text" defaultValue="" placeholder="Name..." />
          <br />
          <TextField onChange={this.handleChange} id="email" type="text" defaultValue="" placeholder="Email..." />
          <br />
          <TextField onChange={this.handleChange} id="phone" type="number" defaultValue="" placeholder="Phone Number" />
          <br />
          <br />
          <Button type="submit" value="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" onSubmit={this.handleChange}> Submit </Button>

        </form>

      </div>
    );

  }

}



export default Form;
```

**Modal.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

function Example() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return (
        <>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                Demo modal
            </Button>

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Body closeButton>
                    Form

                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        Close
                     </Button>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        Save Changes
            </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}


export default Example;
```

Comment: What's the problem? What errors are you getting? What have you tried that's not working?

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60436498/11299053) give you any clue?

Comment: @blaytenshi there is no error, I want to add two things in my project "1. When they click on the button the modal will be open with the form" "2. when clicking on the edit button again modal will open with predefined values and when I edit the fields the table will be updating"

Answer (score 0):

You want to open modal and the modal has a form inside it, right?
So you'll import `Modal.js` file in `App.js`
like that `import Modal from ./Modal.js`

1. And inside the initial state add

```
this.state = {
    people: [],
    showModal: false
};
```

2. Create a function to close model on press close button that inside Modal

```
const handleClose = () =>  this.setState({showModal: false})
```

3. And use the component under this line `<div className="App">`

you'll write:

```
<Modal show={this.state.showModal} email={this.state.email} close={this.handleClose}/>
```

4. Inside this function `editPerson` you must write this code without `return`
   write:

```
this.setState({email, showModal: true})
```

ِAfter that you'll open `Model.js` file and import Form from `Form.js` file 
and change this line

```
<Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
```

to this:

```
<Modal show={props.show} onHide={props.handleClose}>
```

yeah and before I forget you should change this function (component)

`function Example()` to receive props so it'll be

```
function Example(props) {
    ...
}
```