# Send array of objects to render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, react-props

Having an array of this form:

```
[{"game_id":4,"city":"London","year":2018,"athlete_id":"1"},
 {"game_id":2,"city":"Paris","year":2016,"athlete_id":"2"}]
```

it is received from back-end and stored like this:

```
callAPI() {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/testAPI')
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((res) => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
  }
```

and then, in the render is send as props to the Table component:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <header className='App-header'>
          <Table data={this.state.apiResponse} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The problem comes here when I want to send to the table only parts of `apiResponse`.

This is the component:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getGames = function () {
    return this.props.data;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>{this.getGames()}</tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The above code sends all the data, so I tried to send only the data that I want, for example only the keys and make headers out of them.

So I replaces the content of `getGames()` with this:

```
  getGames = function () {
    return Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
  };
```

but it throws this error:

**TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object**

What I want is to create a table with headers: `game_id`, `city`, `year`, `athelete_id` and their columns the show their corresponding data.

Comment: If you need your table data to be flexible (you may want to use it partially or rearrange columns), you need to use [slightly different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60436498/11299053) - prepare header array and map each row based on header.