# Facing Error: Objects are not valid as a React child even though using .map function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, material-ui

i am a bit stuck using array of object in return statement, `allInvoices` are array of objects and i am extracting the info using the .map function and dispaly on screen but i am getting the Error: Objects are not valid as a React child, i am not sure why it is saying that as i am using .map function to go on each index and extracting info from each object before showing on the screen.

**Update1:** the problem seems to with the invoice_document1, as once i exclude it, i can see the other output.invoice_document1 is a pdf file that i am looking to show on screen as a link for the users to download, not sure how can i achieve this. any suggestion please

`invoice_document1` console

[image]

The `snippet` of code below

```
import { makeStyle, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow, Paper, TableContainer } from "@material-ui/core";

function Useraccount({  allInvoices }) {

console.log("8",allInvoices);

 return (
    <>
      <div className="BasketProducts" style={{ float: "left" }}>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Invoice No </TableCell>
                <TableCell> Date of Purchase</TableCell>
                <TableCell> Description</TableCell>
                <TableCell> Invoice</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>

              {allInvoices.map((eachInvoice) => {

                let invoiceNo1 = eachInvoice.invoiceNo;
                let date_of_purchase1 = eachInvoice.date_of_purchase;
                let invoice_document1 = eachInvoice.invoice_document;


                return (
                  <TableRow key={date_of_purchase1}>
                    <TableCell>{invoiceNo1}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{date_of_purchase1}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>TBO</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{invoice_document1}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}

            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

`allInvoices`are an array of object as below

[image]

[image]

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60436498/11299053) may give you a clue on how to approach your problem

Comment: Thanks  Yevgen for the link, i will have a look.  it seems that the problem here is with the pdf file(invoice_document1) that is included in the object, but not sure how can i display as a link for the users to download, i have updated the console of the pdf file above. any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure all of the three variables are `string` or `number`?

```
allInvoices.map((eachInvoice) => {
  let invoiceNo1 = eachInvoice.invoiceNo;
  let date_of_purchase1 = eachInvoice.date_of_purchase;
  let invoice_document1 = eachInvoice.invoice_document;
  ...
})
```

Probably the problem is not related to the `map` itself but to `invoice_document1`

Comment: Thanks Daniele, i think you are right once i exclude the invoice_document1 from the above .map function it does shows all the other items. the invoice_document1 is the pdf file( i have updated above the console of invoice _docuement1) that is retrieve from the backend database, i am looking to show in the table as the attachment for the user to download, not sure how can i achieve that. any suggestion please.

Comment: No @Umair_007 sorry, I never rendered a pdf in a HTML page. Being it a completely different topic I suggest you to ask another question, specific for that topic. Since it seems at least I solved your first problem, could I ask you to kindly accept my answer?