# React render table - match body data to heading data order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

In React, I am rendering a table where the table headings are the "id" values of:

```
"header": [
    {"id": "a"},
    {"id": "b"},
    {"id": "c"},
    {"id": "d"},
    {"id": "e"}
]
```

The table body is rendered from:

```
"body": [
    {
        "d": "Hello",
        "e": "Hey",
        "b": "Hi",
        "a": "Yo",
        "c": "Hella"
    },
    {
        "d": "Hello2",
        "e": "Hey2",
        "b": "Hi2",
        "a": "Yo2",
        "c": "Hella2"
    }
]
```

I am trying to make the Keys of the 'body' objects, to be in the same order as the 'header' objects "id" values (as they have the same values).

So the end result will be...

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Yo</td>
            <td>Hi</td>
            <td>Hella</td>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hey</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yo2</td>
            <td>Hi2</td>
            <td>Hella2</td>
            <td>Hello2</td>
            <td>Hey2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My code so far:

```
render() {
    const header = header.map(item => {
        return <td>{item.id}</td>;
    });
    
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>{header}</tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {body}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

The question here is how do I code the {body} to work as described above please, here's my go so far (but the ordering isn't there as not sure what I need to do):

```
 const body = body.map(item => {
        return (
            <tr>
                {Object.keys(item).map(x => {
                    return <td>{item[x}</td>;
                })}
            </tr>
        );
    });
```

Comment: `<tr>{header.map(col => <td>{item[col.id]</td>)}</tr>`

Comment: You may check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60436498/11299053) for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I took on board what @Chris G and @Yevgen Gorbunkov commented and I came up with a very simple solution that worked for me.

```
const body = body.map(item => {
        return (
            <tr>
                {Object.keys(item).map(x => {
                    return <td>{item[headerItem.id}</td>;
                })}
            </tr>
        );
    });
```